# Not able to Stream video in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass video in bytes from controller and read and play it on jsp. It is working for videos having size less than 1 MB MB but it is not working for files bigger than 1 MB. Please help me..
here is my controller which reads file and writes bytes into output stream.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/playVideo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void  home(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest    request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    String filePath = "D://Uploads//s.mp4";        
    int fileSize = (int) new File(filePath).length();
    response.setContentLength(fileSize);
    response.setContentType("video");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int value = IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    System.out.println("File Size :: "+fileSize);
    System.out.println("Copied Bytes :: "+value);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Here is my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<video width="320" height="240" controls> 

  <source src="/elearningportal/playVideo" type=video/mp4>

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tomcat has limit for max post size (2MB). Please examine it from google.

Comment: "working for videos having size >=1 MB but it is not working for files bigger than 1 MB" If it's working for videos **of size** >= 1MB, it works for files bigger than 1MB. That's part of the definition of >=.

Comment: sorry i mean less than 1 MB..:(

Comment: so now if I want to stream videos which are bigger than 2 MB what I have to do? I changed maxPostSize= "-1" still it is not working... how can I do something like buffering ? what is Red5 server? Do I need that for this ..?please reply..

Comment: It is a 2 years old thread, is the issue resolved?Any hint to resolve this.I am also facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a bigger BufferSize?

```
response.setBufferSize(fileSize);
```